# 403 status code on POST to Angular/Tomcat

Tags: angular, http, tomcat, preflight

I'm writing my first Angular application and I want to make a post request to my backend tomcat server. Using the same information I passed into Postman which returns a 200 OK response to me.

```
myPost(firstname: String, lastname: String, top: String, bottom: String): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8088/myportal/api/myService', JSON.stringify({
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": "1",
      "method": "myPost",
      "params": {firstname,lastname,top,bottom}
    }),{
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'SSOUser': 'ARDC2342FC'
      })
    });
  }
```

I found once solution that says to modify Tomcat config so I edited the Tomcat `web.xml` file to enable the `CorsFilter` to allow all origins.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Still didn't work. I found a solution that talks about using angular proxy so I then created a proxy.config.json file which was one of the previous solutions but it still didn't work

```
{
    "/myportal/api" : {
        "target" : "http://localhost:8088/myportal/api", 
        "secure" : false,
        "logLevel" : "debug", 
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

It still doesn't work. I don't see any other alternate solutions to this issues so I'm just assuming that I did something wrong. Can anyone please help?  If I take out my SSOUser, I get a 500 error which is the same thing that happens on postman so that's the only way I can validate that my frontend request is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a good way to handle the SSOuser header

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error was happening because of the ssouser in the request header.  For some reason it prevented the request to reach the server side. When I took that out I was able to get through to the server. Although I needed to hardcode the ssouser information on the server side just to pass authentication.

I will need to lookup a proper way to send ssouser information in an http request.